# BO - Object in derived table

Tags: business-objects, derived-table

I have a derived table like that in my UNX :

```
select field1, field2
from myTable
where myDate < @Prompt('Choose your date','D',,Mono,,Persistent,,User:-1)
```

I would like to be able to have a prompt where I can choose "the day minus 30 days" before today.
For that, I usually use an object DateCal-X :

```
Case when year(@Prompt('Choose your date','D',,Mono,,Persistent,,User:-1))/100 = 23
then today()-30
else today()
end
```

This way, I choose the year 2300 to have today minus 30 days.

I would like to be able to do something like :

```
select field1, field2
from myTable
where myDate < @Select(DateCal-X)
```

But this raises the error :

> SQL Expression not valid

I can copy the case/when in the query. My problem is that I have 40 derived tables the same way, and it would mean to that 40 times, and change it 40 times every time there is a modification to do.

I am using SAP BO 4.2.

Is there a way to do what I want simply ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using? My syntax below will work in SQL Server. You could adjust if accordingly if you are using a different database.

Do you really need a prompt? This would get you all of the record less than today - 30 days...

```
select field1, field2
from myTable
where myDate < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```

If you really do need a prompt you could replace the "-30" and/or the "GETDATE()" with prompts to capture how far you want to go back and where to start.

Noel

Comment: The prompt is mandatory. The problem is not about getting the date minus 30 days  (i simplified that part, in my case /when i actually have 6 possibilities ), it's more about how to do it in 40 derived table without duplicating the formula 40 times.

Comment: I don't know how to get around dealing with each of the 40 derived tables individually.